# Access parent as well as self controller in Angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StXFK/573/) where I am using `require` property of angular directive for accessing parent controller. Now I want to access both parent and self controller in `link` function of component directive.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div screen>
    <div component>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to access self as well as parent directive controller in `postlink` function of directive

Answer (score 1):

Have found the solution. I just need to mention same directive name in array of require property of directive definition object. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/StXFK/575/)

```
.directive('component', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        require: ['component','^screen'],
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.componentFunction = function() {
                $scope.screenCtrl.doSomethingScreeny();
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, screenCtrl ) {
            scope.screenCtrl = screenCtrl
            console.log(screenCtrl);
        }
    }
})
```